# How to automatic fomat all bigdecimal fields in list <object> with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, list, bigdecimal

My Rest Api (by Spring boot) need automatic convert BigDecimal fields in list of object with thousand format.

Ex :

```
class EmployeeDTO {
     private String name;

     private BigDecimal salary; // 12345 --> need to 12,345
 }

@PostMapping(path = "/get-list-employee")
public ResponseEntity<Object> searchListEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO)
        throws JSONException {
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(employeeService
            .searchListEmployee(employeeDTO).getBody(),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and need return List which each Employee has salary has formatted.

I found some format ways, such as using PropertyEditorRegistrar or CustomNumberFormat, ...

but seem, it not support for list object.

Anyone show me how to format all bigdecimal fields in a list of object ?

Comment: What is the structure of `Employee` class? Can you share the code?

Comment: I've just updated the question. Pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the getter of the `salary` in `EmployeeDTO` to return a formatted value. Like this:

```
public String getSalary() {
    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(salary);
}
```

This will return a formatted value according to JVM's current default `Locale` like this: `$12,345.00`

You can also change this if you provide a custom formatter. Like this:

```
public String getSalary() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
    return df.format(salary);
}
```

It will return a formatted value like this: `12,345.00`.

Here is how I have tested it out:

```
List<EmployeeDTO> employees = new ArrayList<>();
employees.add(new EmployeeDTO("Emp1", BigDecimal.valueOf(12345)));
employees.add(new EmployeeDTO("Emp2", BigDecimal.valueOf(22134)));
employees.add(new EmployeeDTO("Emp3", BigDecimal.valueOf(44233)));

System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(employees)); // printing JSON
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Emp1",
    "salary": "$12,345.00"
  },
  {
    "name": "Emp2",
    "salary": "$22,134.00"
  },
  {
    "name": "Emp3",
    "salary": "$44,233.00"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but I don't want to change type of salary from 'BigDecimal' to 'String', because it's used to mapping to salary in table in DB (NUMBER in ORACLE).
I also don't want to create two DTO classes, one for String (String salary) and one for BigDecimal.


Beside, there are many fields same as 'salary', some fields are dynamic, so if i want to find a automatic change way, such as using CustomNumberFormat.

Comment: I am not asking you to change the type of `salary` from `BigDecimal` to `String`. I have just written a different getter method for the `BigDecimal salary` field.

Comment: thank for your answer.
I found a solution : 
- Write a class : 

public class BigDecimalJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> 
and in EmployeeDTO, I use 
    @JsonSerialize(using = BigDecimalJsonSerializer.class)
     private BigDecimal salary; // 12345 --> 12,345
 }